# How to copy reference to the active list number in Word?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a lot of lists in my document with numbers that look like "1.3.2" and I want to automate the process of creating a cross-references to the list elements.

I'm trying to make a macro that will:

- detect the list element, cursor is positioned at;
- create a cross reference to the list element with number as a reference text (i.e. "1.3.2");
- put it into the clipboard;
- make "LCtrl+C" hotkey launch that macro when cursor is positioned at the list number (optional: only for the lists with declared style(s)).

How do I achieve that with VBA?

Comment: Not sure I understand: "create a cross reference" - _Where_ would you like to create that cross-reference? You are at the _target_ that reference would point to. Where would you want the source link to be? Creating a cross-reference per se is as easy as turning on the macro recorder... Please specify _exactly_ what you want, including expected output and what you have tried so far.

Comment: I want to create it in the clipboard (GeneratedReference.PutInClipboard). Use case: click on the number of the list, Ctrl-C, click anywhere you want to paste cross-refference to that list-element, Ctrl-V, list element number is getting pasted there as a cross-reference.

Comment: This has nothing to do with "cross-reference" then. You can copy text to the clipboard using `DataObject` and `.SetText` as demonstrated here: http://word.mvps.org/faqs/MacrosVBA/ManipulateClipboard.htm and get the list number of the current pargraph using `Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range.ListFormat`. Does that do the trick?

Comment: I want to do the same thing that the Cross Reference window does, when you select reference type "Numbered item" and insert reference to "Paragraph number" (http://i.imgur.com/biByqFj.png), But to do this without the window and insert cross referrence in the clipboard instead of the document straight ahead. The document has too many lists, so it's hard to use that window. It would save a lot of time if we could copy-paste them with hotkeys only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at the object model and how Word behaves I think you can manage something, but perhaps not exactly the way you envisioned. The problem lies with the Numbered Items, which seem to be oriented to captions rather than numbered lines... In any case, when a cross-reference is inserted via the dialog box to a "Numbered item" Word does create a bookmark and then reference that. So my suggestion emulates that behavior, as in the following code snippet.

What you'll need/want to do is maintain a "counter" for incrementing the bookmark name (or you could generate GUIDs, the way Word does). My demo has the bookmark name hard-coded.

This example sets the *hidden* bookmark at the beginning of the paragraph where the current selection is. It then inserts a cross-reference, extends the Range to include the cross-reference (since the method does not return a range or object) and cuts it to the clipboard. The user can then paste it wherever he wants.

```
Sub InsertThenCopyCrossRef()
    Dim rng As word.Range, rngBkm As word.Range
    Dim bkm As word.Bookmark
    Dim sMyRef As String

    sMyRef = "_MyRef_1" 'a counter or something to make name unique!
    Set rng = Selection.Range
    Set rngBkm = rng.Duplicate.Paragraphs(1).Range
    rngBkm.Collapse wdCollapseStart
    Set bkm = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add(sMyRef, rngBkm)
    rng.InsertCrossReference wdRefTypeBookmark, wdNumberFullContext, sMyRef
    rng.MoveEnd wdWord, 1
    rng.Fields(1).Cut
    'rng.Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to emulate the window logic, but your solution does exactly what I needed.
I just added timestamp as UID for new References:
sMyRef = "_MyRef_" & DateDiff("s", #1/1/1970#, Now())
And added InsertAsHyperlink:=True to this line:
rng.InsertCrossReference wdRefTypeBookmark, wdNumberFullContext, sMyRef, True
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yeah, probably better with a bookmark. Does the cut work too? It didn't when I tried it. I did have a RDP open that could have messed with my clipboard but copy and cut didn't work for me there with the field.

Comment: @LocEngineer Yes, the cut works. It looks a bit strange when it adds a line of the text and immediately removes it, but it does the trick. Much better way to create bookmarks to the list elements than using standard window.

Comment: @LocEngineer. Your code uses PutInClipboard instead of cut, and as far as I can tell is only taking the text, not the field?

Comment: @CindyMeister Yes. Like I said for some reason it would not copy the field correctly, paste would yield nothing. So I created a temporary crossref, copied the field code to clipboard. The second code then creates a new field and sets the field code to the clipboard contents. Long-winded but it simply did not copy the field try as I may.

Comment: @LocEngineer. Huh, would have been interesting to watch over your shoulder :-) For future reference, that's why the rng.Select (commented out) is in there. I had to try a couple of times, as well. Writing to Field.Code won't encompass the entire field, so the MoveEnd is in there to ensure I pick up all of it before cutting.

Answer (score 0):

I've tinkered around for the fun of it and long story short: I don't think you will manage to do that. Reason: this is the code for creating a cross reference to a numbered item in VBA:

```
Set r = Selection.Range

r.InsertCrossReference ReferenceType:="Numbered item", _
        ReferenceKind:=wdNumberRelativeContext, ReferenceItem:="5", _
        InsertAsHyperlink:=True, IncludePosition:=False, SeparateNumbers:=False, _
        SeparatorString:=" "
```

Trouble here is the ReferenceItem:="5". When I recorded this, it was simply the fifth numbered item regardless of its list level.
So all you have to do now is to find a way to identify a numbered item as the nth numbered item in your document.

If you can solve that, you can assign a key combination to copy a reference to the current list item like this:

```
Sub CopyReference()
Dim r As Range
Dim dObject As DataObject

Set dObject = New DataObject

Set r = Selection.Range

r.InsertCrossReference ReferenceType:="Nummeriertes Element", _
        ReferenceKind:=wdNumberRelativeContext, ReferenceItem:="5", _
        InsertAsHyperlink:=True, IncludePosition:=False, SeparateNumbers:=False, _
        SeparatorString:=" "

dObject.SetText r.Paragraphs(1).Range.Fields(1).Code
r.Paragraphs(1).Range.Fields(1).Delete
dObject.PutInClipboard

End Sub
```

And another key combination to paste your reference like this:

```
Sub pasteField()
Dim fld As Field, dObject As DataObject
Dim gg

Set fld = ActiveDocument.Fields.Add(Selection.Range, wdFieldRef)
Set dObject = New DataObject
dObject.GetFromClipboard
gg = dObject.GetText
fld.Code.Text = gg
fld.Update
End Sub
```

As you can see, I haven't actually copied the cross reference field but only its code.